# One field of my simple c++ doesn't change like others

Tags: c++

So, I have this:

```
class vector3f
{
public:

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float w;

    vector3f(void)
    {
        x = 0.0f;
        y = 0.0f;
        z = 0.0f;
        w = 1.0f;
    }
};
```

There is other functions here, but I don't use them for the part that cause problem.
And I have this function:

```
vector3f mult_matrix_vector(matrix4x4f m, vector3f v)
{
    vector3f result;
    result.x = m.m[0]*v.x + m.m[4]*v.y + m.m[8]*v.z  + m.m[12]*v.w;
    result.y = m.m[1]*v.x + m.m[5]*v.y + m.m[9]*v.z  + m.m[13]*v.w;
    result.z = m.m[2]*v.x + m.m[6]*v.y + m.m[10]*v.z + m.m[14]*v.w;
    result.w = m.m[3]*v.x + m.m[7]*v.y + m.m[11]*v.z + m.m[15]*v.w;
    return result;
}
```

The function receive a matrix 4x4 and a vector on homogeneous coordinates (the name has a `3` because I only needed the homogeneous coordinate later). If I try something like: `v2 = mult_matrix_vector(m, v);` the `x`, `y` and `z` of `v2` are the correct result of the multiplication, but `w` is ALWAYS `1`. Does anyone knows why this happens?

EDIT:

A more numerical example:

I have a matrix `m` like this:

```
1    0    0 -441
0    1    0  224
0    0   -1 1452
0    0   -1 1463
```

Then this code:

```
matrix4x4f m = mult_matrix(my_projection, my_modelview);
vector3f v, v2;
v2 = mult_matrix_vector(m, v);
```

`m` get as result of the multiplication as I showed above. `v1` is `0 0 0 1`, since I didn't change it. `v2` should be `-441 224 1452 1463`, but it become `-441 224 1452 1`.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be?

Comment: What inputs are you using? It's hard to say how it'd transform. Unless you're trying to translate an object in 3D space though, I wouldn't expect the `w` parameter of the vector to change...

Comment: If `m.m[15]==1` and `v.w==1`, then `result.w==1`. And no matter how many times you pass the result vector back into the function, the result will be 1

Comment: `m` is a multiplication of a projection and a modelview matrices, so `w` should change, but it doesn't. I made a matrix that would change the value of `w`, but it's always 1.

Comment: I guess it's time for you to show us that matrix. In other words, where is your [testcase](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: So you are saying that your values of m.m[3], [7], [11] and [15] result in w not being 1. And in a debugger result.w is being set accordingly but upon return the v2 does not have the expected w value? If so there must be some code missing because what is pasted looks like it should work.

Comment: Do you ever change the values of `v.x, v.y, v.z,` or `v.w`?

Comment: Code works fine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfb211b02a10faa3

Comment: I'm stupid! Thanks for the help. I found the problem. Sory to bother with my stupidity. I'm posting the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
result.w = m.m[3]*v.x + m.m[7]*v.y + m.m[11]*v.z + m.m[15]*v.w;
```

is equivalent to:

```
result.w = m.m[15]*v.w;
```

if `v.x`, `v.y`, and `v.z` are always set to `0.0`, like you indicate.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I didn't adapted the vector3f properly when adding `w`. The `=` shouldn't just pass the reference, so the vector3f had this:

```
vector3f& vector3f::operator = ( const vector3f &other )
{
    x = other.x;
    y = other.y;
    z = other.z;

    return *this;
}
```

I adapted the other functions, but forgot this one, so the value of `w`was never passed on `=` operation. The correct is:

```
vector3f& vector3f::operator = ( const vector3f &other )
{
    x = other.x;
    y = other.y;
    z = other.z;
    w = other.w;

    return *this;
}
```

I passed 2 days trying to find what was wrong with my program and then more than 2 hours trying to find why `w` didn't changed just to find this. Sory to bother people here with my stupidity.

Comment: Good for you that were able to identify the source of your problem.